# TypeError: argument of type 'int' is not iterable

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.x, dict

```
// Telegram bot
control_quantity = {}

if message.chat.id in control_quantity:
    control_quantity[message.chat.id] += 1
else:
    control_quantity[message.chat.id] = 1
```

Получаю ошибку:

```
if message.chat.id in control_quantity:
**TypeError: argument of type 'int' is not iterable**
```

В чем ошибка? Помогите пожалуйста!

Comment: message.chat.id это какой тип? int str

Answer (score 0):

Интерпретатор сообщает Вам о том, что по типу `int` нельзя итерироваться. Т.е. тип `int` -- это не коллекция. Пример коллекций:

```
[1, 2, 3]

{1:1, 2:2, 3:3}

import collections
c = collections.Counter()
```

Вам нужно понять, что лежит в `message.chat.id` и в `message.chat.id`. Для этого воспользуетесь отладочным выводом

```
// Telegram bot
control_quantity = {}


print(control_quantity)
print(message)
print(message.chat)
print(message.chat.id)
if message.chat.id in control_quantity:
    control_quantity[message.chat.id] += 1
else:
    control_quantity[message.chat.id] = 1
```

Скорее всего, Вы обнаружите нестыковки в данных в одном из этих выводов